# How to stream phone screen hidden from user?

Tags: android, rtsp, rtmp

Using this library https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java I can easely stream phone camera hidden from user but I can't stream phone display hidden from user because it requires user confirmation for screen streaming.

Here is the axample of screen streaming https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pedro/rtpstreamer/displayexample/DisplayRtspActivity.java

> **rtspDisplay.sendIntent()** - use **MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()** method which is requered for screen capture 
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html#createScreenCaptureIntent()

```
...
startActivityForResult(rtspDisplay.sendIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_STREAM);
...
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_STREAM
        || requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECORD && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      if (rtspDisplay.prepareAudio() && rtspDisplay.prepareVideo()) {
        initNotification();
        rtspDisplay.setIntentResult(resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_STREAM) {
          rtspDisplay.startStream(etUrl.getText().toString());
        } else {
          try {
            rtspDisplay.startRecord(folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + currentDateAndTime + ".mp4");
          } catch (IOException e) {
            rtspDisplay.stopRecord();
            bRecord.setText(R.string.start_record);
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error preparing stream, This device cant do it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
      }
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "No permissions available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
```

How I can stream phone screen hidden from user using any other libraries or using Root?
I am new to android development...

Any advices are welcome!

Comment: "How I can stream phone screen hidden from user using any other libraries" -- hopefully that is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok how about root? I can stream phone camera hidden from user if android version lower than 9 even without root

Comment: This user confirmation is not part of the system, but of the library itself. You can change the Java code to bypass it.

Comment: @AlexCohn User confirmation is part of the system library MediaProjectionManager .... method createScreenCaptureIntent() required for screen capture https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html#createScreenCaptureIntent()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using root and screenrecord system command.... This is not realtime, but this is better than nothing!